# How to fixe error in jupyter notebook: Image data cannot be converted to float?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter

I need somebody's help.

I also tried the following **code** and got an error (it's about pix2pix and the result doesnt show in this section any photo):

```
import tensorflow as tf

import os
import time
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython import display

PATH = os.path.join('datasets/','facades/', 'train/')

BUFFER_SIZE = 400
BATCH_SIZE = 1
IMG_WIDTH = 256
IMG_HEIGHT = 256

inp, re = load(PATH+'train/100.jpg')

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(inp/255.0)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(re/255.0)
```

This is the **error**:

```
  TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-0ddde1d49d08> in <module>
      2 
      3 plt.figure()
----> 4 plt.imshow(inp/255.0)
      5 plt.figure()
      6 plt.imshow(re/255.0)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\generative\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in imshow(X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, data, **kwargs)
   2699         filternorm=filternorm, filterrad=filterrad, imlim=imlim,
   2700         resample=resample, url=url, **({"data": data} if data is not
-> 2701         None else {}), **kwargs)
   2702     sci(__ret)
   2703     return __ret

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\generative\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1808                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1809                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1810             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1811 
   1812         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\generative\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in imshow(self, X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, **kwargs)
   5492                               resample=resample, **kwargs)
   5493 
-> 5494         im.set_data(X)
   5495         im.set_alpha(alpha)
   5496         if im.get_clip_path() is None:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\generative\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in set_data(self, A)
    640         if (self._A.dtype != np.uint8 and
    641                 not np.can_cast(self._A.dtype, float, "same_kind")):
--> 642             raise TypeError("Image data cannot be converted to float")
    643 
    644         if not (self._A.ndim == 2

TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float
```

I also try this for path too but got the same **error**:

```
 _URL = 'https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~tinghuiz/projects/pix2pix/datasets/facades.tar.gz'

path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file('facades.tar.gz',
                                      origin=_URL,
                                      extract=True)

PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path_to_zip), 'facades/')
```

Comment: This error usually means that you aren't reading in the image properly.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that you are not reading in the image properly.

I have tried execute [pix2pix](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix) code in Colab and it ran successfully. Please can you try below code and let us know if you are facing any issue.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
import os
import time
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython import display

_URL = 'https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~tinghuiz/projects/pix2pix/datasets/facades.tar.gz'

path_to_zip = tf.keras.utils.get_file('facades.tar.gz',
                                      origin=_URL,
                                      extract=True)

PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path_to_zip), 'facades/')

BUFFER_SIZE = 400
BATCH_SIZE = 1
IMG_WIDTH = 256
IMG_HEIGHT = 256

def load(image_file):
  image = tf.io.read_file(image_file)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)

  w = tf.shape(image)[1]

  w = w // 2
  real_image = image[:, :w, :]
  input_image = image[:, w:, :]

  input_image = tf.cast(input_image, tf.float32)
  real_image = tf.cast(real_image, tf.float32)

  return input_image, real_image
  
inp, re = load(PATH+'train/100.jpg')

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(inp/255.0)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(re/255.0)
```

You set path as below, only if you have `datasets` in your current working directory.

```
PATH = os.path.join('datasets/','facades/')
inp, re = load(PATH+'train/100.jpg')
```

or

```
PATH = os.path.join('datasets/','facades/', 'train/')
inp, re = load(PATH+'100.jpg')
```